# Secured and unsecured items message in IE

Tags: dojo

I'm  getting "This page contains bothe Secure and Non secure items"message in IE. When I commented the following piece of code from dojo.js.uncompressed.js file, the message is gone.

```
if(dojo.isIE){
  if(!dojo.config.afterOnLoad){
    document.write('<scr'+'ipt defer src="//:" '
      + 'onreadystatechange="if(this.readyState==\'complete\'){' + dojo._scopeName + '._loadInit();}">'
      + '</scr'+'ipt>'
    );
}
```

Is that an issue with the dojo? I would like to move the commented code to another custom file so that the dojo framework is not affected. Can you suggest a better way of implementing it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would get that error if you're using frames or have external files where some of the files have **https** URLs while some have **http** URLs. Assuming, your main page loads up through https, you could try changing:

```
src="//:"
```

to:

```
src="https//:"
```

Answer (score 0):

the //: is most likely the problem, as I ran into a similar issue with a chunk of javascript code... In internet explorer, the locaiton //: is not secure, so when your page (presumably on an https:// url) loads, IE notes that you've got your main code loading from a secure location, and another script being loaded in from an unsecure location.

The workaround that I came to was to create an empty file in my web root named "blank.html" (though "blank.js" would probably work better in your case) and replace the //: link with "/blank.html".  This results in another hit to your webserver, but browser caching will probably make that impact minimal.